# Laravel 5.2 RefectionException

Tags: reflection, controller, laravel-5

A newbie question ...

To open the first page (index) I have the following in a GamesController:

```
 public function index()
{
    //show a listing of games
    $games = Game::all();
    return view('index',['games'=> $games]);
}
```

which works fine. I have at the top of the controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Game;
```

The model is simply

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Game extends Model
{
    //
}
```

In my index page I have a simple list from the db with an edit button which has the code:

```
<a href="{{ action('GamesController@edit',  ['id' => $game->id]) }}" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a>
```

In my controller have the following:

```
public function edit(Request $request)
        {
            $games = Game::find($request->id);
            return view('edit',['games'=>$games]);
        }
```

but when I press the edit button I get

[image]

Comment: there are many errors in your code, I will suggest you to followup with a CRUD tutorial , https://www.sitepoint.com/crud-create-read-update-delete-laravel-app/

Comment: Thanks I will read that. The code above is actually from a tutorial.

Comment: Well I solved it. The tutorial you mention by the way is for a previous version of Laravel. The tutorial I was following said to start the routes file with Route::model('game','Game'); and it was this line was the mistake. I think the tutorial was for an earlier version even though it says it has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

do not put

```
Route::model('game','Game');
```

at the beginning of routes